# styled-component is not compatible with react 18

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have installed latest version of react, but can't use styled component because versions are not compatible, so i installed version 17 of react. Is any way to use react 18 with styled-component?

Comment: Styled components work fine with react 18 https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-bas-ywg6qh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hmm interesting, so may be i did some wrong things, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.